# MySql_fetch_array() error in PHP when using while

Tags: php, mysql, loops, while-loop

Ok so here is my code:

```
$select_status = 0;
$select_status = "<select name='status'>\n";
$select_status .= "<option value=''>SELECT ONE</option>\n";
$sdataset = mysql_query("SELECT id, name FROM phponly_category") or die(mysql_error());

while($srow=mysql_fetch_assoc($sdataset)) {
    echo implode(", ", $srow);
    echo "<br />";

    $select_status .= "<option value='".$srow['name']."'";
    $select_status .= ">".$srow['name']."</option>\n";


} // end while loop
echo "out of the loop";
$select_status .= "</select>\n";
// now insert the <select> list control into the page
echo $select_status;
```

The code works fine until the last row when it breaks. I cannot get the *echo $select_status* printed.
I have tried to see what is going on with the SQL query results by printing each row but everything looks fine there. For some reason, at the last row the *while loop* breaks and even the code after *while loop* doesn't get executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally don't like to echo out html code, if your goal is to do validate whether there's result comes out of the query, you can do something like this

```
<?php
    $sdataset = mysql_query("SELECT id, name FROM phponly_category");
    if (mysql_num_rows($sdataset) > 0) {
?>
    <select name='status'>
    <option value=''>SELECT ONE</option>
<?php
    while($srow = mysql_fetch_array($sdataset)) {
?>
    <option value='<?php echo $srow['name'] ?>'><?php echo $srow['name'] ?></option>
<?php } // end while loop ?>
    </select>
<?php
    } // end of if
    else {
        // Whatever you wanna put here
    }
?>
```

EDITED: There's a typo at `mysql_num_rows`, try this one again

Comment: Ok I tried your approach without the echo :). It worked well for me. I can say that the problem is solved. Thank you!

Comment: You make a good point about echoing out HTML.  However, this is virtually the same thing.  We're still mixing implementation and logic.  Best to do your processing first, then render.  Use templates if possible.  Much easier to read/debug/maintain.

Comment: @pyrospade yea, echo works, I prefer this way because I think it presents the code more clearly

Answer (score 1):

Don't do the `or die(mysql_error())` portion in the while test...do it before.

```
if($sdataset==false) {
    die(mysql_error());
}
while($srow=mysql_fetch_array($sdataset)) {
    $select_status .= "<option value='".$srow['name']."'".">".$srow['name']."</option>\n";
} // end while loop
```

Comment: For some strange reason, now when use echo implode(",", $srow); now I see that I get double values for my columns as 1, 1, Computers, Computers. I checked my sql, it looks ok. I don't get what can be wrong. Otherwise, I don;t get any better results neither errors.

Comment: Probably a good idea to ask a new question so we can address it accordingly.  Post the rest of the code so we can have some context.

Comment: the double values part solved, but still the while loop breaks.

Answer (score 1):

The `or die()` on your while() loop will actually kill the script when you read the end of the result set. mysql_fetch will return false, triggering the `or die()`.

While checking for errors is good on queries, you can't do it like this on the fetching part, because you get false positives like this.

Comment: Well, I added the die later on to see what the problem is. I removed the die now, and still I don't get any output neither error.

Comment: @acaushi have you checked the output like $srow=mysql_fetch_array($sdataset); print_r($srow);

Comment: I checked the output of the $srow using echo implode(",", $srow);, there is one problem with that. I get double values for every column. for example 1, 1, Computers, Computers.

Comment: @acaushi: RTFM: http://php.net/mysql_fetch_array  array fetches as both associative and indexed array. You probably want fetch_assoc instead, which is associated only

Comment: Ok, associated solved the problem of double columns. Still, I don't understand why the while loop breaks

Comment: mysql_fetch returns false when there's no data to retrieve. After you hit the end of your result set, it returns false, which triggers the die. hence your script kills itself at the end of the loop. you don't do any output in the loop, so effectively you see nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Use `mysql_fetch_assoc` so you can get the data using the field name as the key.

```
<?php

$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password');
mysql_select_db('test');

$select_status = "<select name='status'>\n";
$select_status .= "<option value=''>SELECT ONE</option>\n";
$sdataset = mysql_query("SELECT id, name FROM phponly_category") or die(mysql_error());

while($srow=mysql_fetch_assoc($sdataset)) {
    $select_status .= "<option value='".$srow['name']."'".">".$srow['name']."</option>\n";

} // end while loop

$select_status .= "</select>\n";
echo $select_status;
?>
```

Note: The use of this extension is discouraged. Take a look at mysqli or PDO.

Comment: I changed to mysql_fetch_assoc, the while loop still breaks and I cannot get to echo $select_status;